# Use yescrypt password hashing scheme with Openldap

Tags: ubuntu, hash, openldap, crypt

I have an Ubuntu 22.04.3 OS :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Ubuntu man page says ubuntu 22.4 crypt function supports yescrypt: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/crypt.5.html, but it says

> Provided by: libcrypt-dev_4.4.27-1_amd64

(which seems weird to me as I don't have this package installed, but crypt() seems available)

I have instead package libcrypt1 in version 4.4.27-1:

```
libcrypt1/jammy,now 1:4.4.27-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Here my ldif to activate it:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
replace: olcPasswordHash
olcPasswordHash: {CRYPT}

dn: cn=config
add: olcPasswordCryptSaltFormat
olcPasswordCryptSaltFormat: $y$%.128s
```

I used here 128 bits of salt knowing that man page says :

> Salt size: up to 512 (128+ recommended) bits

If I'm modifying a new password/creating a new one, after decoding my b64 "userPassword" attribute, I have the value {CRYPT}*0

An "olcPasswordCryptSaltFormat" set to "olcPasswordCryptSaltFormat: $6$%.16s" works perfectly. Issue is with yescrypt algorithm.

PS:
The link at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/amd64/libcrypt1 which gives description about what comes with libcrypt1 package says :

> libxcrypt is a modern library for one-way hashing of passwords.
> It supports DES, MD5, NTHASH, SUNMD5, SHA-2-256, SHA-2-512, and
> bcrypt-based password hashes

Which is different than what https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man5/crypt.5.html pretends (yescrypt, gost-yescrypt and scrypt supported). I'm confused. what do i need to replace/install to get yescrypt working with crypt() (used with my OpenLDAP) by default on Ubuntu22.04 ?

**EDIT**

Okay, well it seems it simply because my crypt function doesn't support yescrypt.
Here the test I did:

```
import crypt

supported_methods = crypt.methods
print(crypt.methods)
```

Here the output:

```
[<crypt.METHOD_SHA512>, <crypt.METHOD_SHA256>, <crypt.METHOD_BLOWFISH>, <crypt.METHOD_MD5>, <crypt.METHOD_CRYPT>]
```

How can I make libcrypt1 to support latest hashing algorithm as yescrypt ?